# getting HTTP Status 401 - unauthorized user error for ebayclassifeids Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ebay-api

I have to use ebayclassifieds Api I am making this request:
curl --digest -u {username}:{password} http://webapi.ebayclassifieds.com/webapi/categories

but I am getting error

```html
<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.26 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP authentication ().</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.26</h3></body></html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to show your code if we're to have any hope of debugging your problem. Also specify which version of Rails 3 you're running please.

Comment: Please format your error message.

Comment: @lorenz Please run the snippet you will see the formatted error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eBay  classifieds (kijiji) have closed their API now. So you will not be able to leverage their services, at the time of posting this.

And coming to Craigslit, They donot have public API either. Programmableweb reported the same(http://blog.programmableweb.com/...) recently.

However, Scraping craigslist is no big deal(thanks to their simple UI) :) . do this if you just want to give it a try, personally I am not a bug fan of scraping.

Finally, Stay glued to Programmableweb.com for any updates on APIs. Its the best place.